# How to move to the rust's reference in neovim?

Tags: rust, reference, neovim

I've installed neovim 5.0 as well as rust-analyzer and configured lsp with the following setting (https://github.com/sharksforarms/vim-rust/blob/master/neovim-init-lsp.vim).

```
  nnoremap <silent> <c-]> <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>
  nnoremap <silent> K     <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>
  nnoremap <silent> gD    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>
  nnoremap <silent> <c-k> <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>
  nnoremap <silent> 1gD   <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.type_definition()<CR>
  nnoremap <silent> gr    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.references()<CR>
  nnoremap <silent> g0    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.document_symbol()<CR>
  nnoremap <silent> gW    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.workspace_symbol()<CR>
```

With `Ctrl+]` shortcut, I can move to the function definition.
With `gr` shortcut, I can see the list of references in the bottom window.
However, I have no idea of how to select the reference and move to the reference (like in cscope).

Is there any way to move to the bottom window and move to the rust's reference in neovim?

Comment: I don't know neovim, but in standard vim you can use `Ctrl-W Ctrl-W` to switch between windows. And `:q` closes the current window, so if you switch to the reference window, hitting `:q` should close it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you mentioned, I could switch between windows using `Ctrl-w-j (move to the window below the selected window)` and `Ctrl-w-k (move to the window above the seleted window)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `:q` shows the reference in the full window after `gr`. In this condition, I could select the reference with `arrow` and move to the reference with `enter`.

However, I am still wondering that how to conveniently close the reference window. Once the reference window has been popped up in the bottom, I do not know how to close it.

Also, I am curious whether there is any way to move to the small reference window without using `:q`.

Comment: that would be `:close`